# Filter data by names in common to a job SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi guys I currently am dealing with an issue and I want to see if there is a way to do this

A staff member wants to see a report that shows the number of hours she has in all of the jobs she worked on, plus the hours for all other staff who also worked on those jobs.  So if my data looks like this:

```
Client-----     Job------   Staff------     Hours    
A-----------    1 --------  Caty----------  15    
A-----------    1 --------  John----------  10    
A-----------    1 --------  Greg----------  6     
B-----------    2 --------  Caty----------  8    
B-----------    2 --------  Ralph-------    10    
B-----------    2 --------  Derek-------    12     
C-----------    1 --------  Steve -------   9      
C-----------    1 --------  Bill----------  20     
C-----------    1 --------  Mike--------    18
```

For Caty, the report should give me this:

```
Client-----     Job------   Staff------     Hours    
A-----------    1 --------  Caty----------  15    
A-----------    1 --------  John----------  10    
A-----------    1 --------  Greg----------  6     
B-----------    2 --------  Caty----------  8    
B-----------    2 --------  Ralph-------    10    
B-----------    2 --------  Derek-------    12
```

I cannot put in the WHERE clause “WHERE Staff=’Caty’” because that would filter out John, Greg, Ralph and Derek, leaving me with only Caty’s hours.

```
select clientcode, clientname, job_name, staffcode, sum(wiphours) as Hours
from tbltranwip w
inner join tblengagement e on e.ContIndex=w.ContIndex
inner join tblJob_Header h on h.Job_Idx=w.ServPeriod
inner join tblstaff s on s.StaffIndex=w.StaffIndex
where wipdate between 'jul 1 2015' and 'jul 31 2015' and TransTypeIndex=1 
and w.ContIndex<900000 and staffcode = 'Caty'
group by clientcode, clientname, job_name, staffcode
```

That code only show's me Caty :S

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table or view looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE job(
    Client char(1) NOT NULL,
    Job int NOT NULL,
    Staff varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Hours int NOT NULL
);

insert into job values
('A',1, 'Caty', 15),
('A',1, 'John', 10),
('A',1, 'Greg', 6),
('B',2, 'Caty', 8),
('B',2, 'Ralph', 10),
('B',2, 'Derek', 12),
('C',1, 'Steve', 9),
('C',1, 'Bill', 20),
('C',1, 'Mike', 18);
```

You could write a query like so to retrieve desired information:

```
select client, job, staff, sum(hours) as totalhours
from job x
where exists (
    select 1 
    from job 
    where staff = 'Caty'
    and client = x.client
    and job = x.job)
group by client, job, staff
```

Result:

```
client job         staff                totalhours
------ ----------- -------------------- -----------
A      1           Caty                 15
A      1           Greg                 6
A      1           John                 10
B      2           Caty                 8
B      2           Derek                12
B      2           Ralph                10
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88075/1

**Possibly try this to resolve your issue**

```
with data as (
    select clientcode, clientname, job_name, staffcode, sum(wiphours) as Hours
    from tbltranwip w
    inner join tblengagement e on e.ContIndex=w.ContIndex
    inner join tblJob_Header h on h.Job_Idx=w.ServPeriod
    inner join tblstaff s on s.StaffIndex=w.StaffIndex
    where wipdate between 'jul 1 2015' and 'jul 31 2015' and TransTypeIndex=1 
    and w.ContIndex<900000
    group by clientcode, clientname, job_name, staffcode
)

select clientcode, job_name, staffcode, sum(wiphours) as Hours
from data x
where exists (
    select 1 
    from data
    where staffcode = 'Caty'
    and clientcode= x.clientcode
    and job_name= x.job_name)
group by clientcode, job_name, staffcode
```

Comment: @andres It works as expected. I'd recommend that you create a table using the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements and then run the query against it. You should see the right results.

Comment: I have done it just as you showed and it works, however when I run it with data on my database, I am getting data from 3 different tables and joining them.  I tried adding your part of the code into mine and it only displays Caty.  See my code above.  I have inner joins and so I try to add your way and i am not sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: I have added SQL that may address your problem. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: your script works only if I change the bottom portion sum(wiphours) as Hours to sum(hours) as Hours.  Everything works as I want but it does not give me the totals for each person.  So instead of giving me     

A Caty 10       
A John 12  
it's giving me A Caty 5 A Caty 5 and A John 6 A John 3 A John 3 ... meaning it is not giving me each persons total even though the sum(wiphours) as Hours is supposed to do that :S

Comment: Can you print the output of the query in you have in your question but change `and w.ContIndex<900000 and staffcode = 'Caty'` to `and w.ContIndex<900000`?

Answer (score 0):

You could select the jobs caty worked in, in a subquery, which you join the get the result

```
Select sum(hours) from timetable t
inner join (select client, job from timetable where staff = 'caty') as sub 
on t.client = sub.client and t.job = sub.job
```

This should get you started

Answer (score 0):

To get the staff that worked on the same jobs as Caty you'll want to use the `in` predicate with a subquery; something like

```
where ...
and job in (select job from appropriate_table where Staff='Caty')
```

I'm not sure how your tables relate so you'll want to adjust the code as needed, but it should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your where clause:
staffcode = 'Caty' or StaffCode in (select staffers from the same group as Caty)

Comment: I do not understand what to put in (select staffers from...as caty) what goes inside the parenthesis